# Do not consider feed bots in the StackExchange™ MultiChannel ChatPreviewer™

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, chat

Users with a negative user ID number (= feeds) should not be considered at all in the Visit Chat in-house ads (that's the StackExchange™ MultiChannel ChatPreviewer™ for the rest of us).

[image: Gaming is shown as the last person talking in the 'General' room, despite it not being an actual human.]

The rationale is that having bots count as chatting basically is false advertisement: they're not an actual human being you can chat with.

Comment: Yeah right, "actual human". Come on now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That makes sense, so.... done; *strictly* speaking it isn't limited on the user-id, but on a separate marker we use to track what each item is - but the effect is the same.