# Stack Exchange Usercard Squeezer™ on profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

[image]

Look at the profile page of [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1155209/jewelsea), who has just "lost" 100k reputation and all their bronze badges, because of this broken design.

Shouldn't the primary usercard be kept intact no matter how other elements grow?

P.S. So many design bugs these days, did SE do a large CSS refactory?

P.P.S [Another instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhfLp.png) that squeezes the right pane ([link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/206160/akash-b) to reproduce)

Comment: Meta.SO duplicate: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374682/the-profile-page-is-scrambled

Comment: Why is there at "™" following _"Stack Exchange Usercard Squeezer"_? Is Stack Exchange really attempting to assert intellectual property rights for the phrase?

Comment: @guest271314 just a joke on SE's wacky features' name like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68796), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69230), [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67160), and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314796)...

Comment: @Somewhat https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316142/350567

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've indeed done some CSS refactoring, and this edge case has now been fixed. It'll go live in the next build.

Comment: May I know the build number? It's 31778 now.

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ seems to be fixed in rev 2018.10.2.31780; current build here (and I assume to be rolled out shortly). Compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/307083/nsnoob (here) with https://stackoverflow.com/users/4029561/nsnoob (SO).