# Backtick escapes on profile causing terrible display

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, profile-page, backtick

This is not a duplicate of [Stack Exchange Usercard Squeezer™ on profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316111/stack-exchange-usercard-squeezer-on-profile-page) as that is a completely different bug that has since been fixed.

So it has come to my attention that when you use backtick escapes to format your profile details the entire display is altered. Here's an example of what I mean:

[image]

You can't see your avatar, badges or rep, and the Impact on the right of the page.

Comment: Thanks, mate! 'Tis even on my [Meta profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/403302/user477343?tab=profile) :P

Comment: @user477343 No prob. Well if it affects one community then it would usually affect all of them

Comment: The fact that my profile avatar isn't there might be intuitively explained by [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316111/stack-exchange-usercard-squeezer-on-profile-page) :)

Comment: Voting to reopen: Squeeze left and squeeze right are two different problems (and have different causes)

Comment: This appears to have been fixed somewhere along the way, but can't readily point to which change would've done it.