# Stack Exchange Aboutme Extender™ with code formatting on profile page

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

Along similar lines to [Stack Exchange Usercard Squeezer™ on profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316111/345161) long code blocks in the "About me" section push the right side content off of the screen. See [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/257322/neil).

[image: About me bug SE]

And it's more pronounced effect on [SFF](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2324/neil).

[image: About me bug SFF]

Also bad on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/467968/neil).

Comment: The reason is the `width: auto` with no `overflow: scroll` on the `pre code`. That would be useful to add here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backtick escapes on profile causing terrible display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316221/backtick-escapes-on-profile-causing-terrible-display)

Comment: @ɪʙᴜɢ That's been marked as a duplicate of the [status-completed] post. Considering this, this shouldn't really be dupe closed should it?

Comment: True but if/when it will be reopened this one can be closed as dupe of it.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder That [status-completed] post is reporting a different bug. That link above has since been reopened.