# Some profile pages are messed up in sites with the new responsive design

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, responsive-design

Few examples across the network:

- [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/243696/35093731895230467514051?tab=profile):

  > [image]
- [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/206160/akash-b):

  > [image]
- [IPS.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/users/2486/drf):

  > [image]

Can this please be fixed? Pretty sure it's related to the responsive design or left nav bar somehow, though can't see what's really causing it.

Comment: Seems related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316111/stack-exchange-usercard-squeezer-on-profile-page)..Stretched on the other side ?

Comment: Stack Exchange™ MultiSqueezer™

Comment: @SurajRao yes indeed... maybe fixing that bug caused this new bug...

Comment: I think it is not just because the `name` also because the description...

Comment: @לבנימלכה no this is surely due to the unbreakable name.

Comment: I tried to add spaces in dev tool nothing happend(or the width generate in other code?)

Comment: From Physics Meta [Profile views, location section moved to extreme right corner](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10843/205676). I thought it's site specific. Actually, it's not display names. It is something with long info in "About Me"

Comment: @NogShine huh, so weird. Let's leave it to the devs to hunt down, maybe it's a combo of several things causing this.

Comment: It's not the long display name, see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1kMU.png

Comment: @CharlieBrumbaugh thanks. edited and gave this as example.

Comment: @לבנימלכה hey, I owe you an apology. You were correct after all. Sorry, and thanks! :)

Comment: MSO [dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375028/is-profile-page-in-meta-is-broken)

Comment: @SurajRao no, that's a wrong dupe. [This one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375195/profile-page-display-bug-on-users-keeping-a-low-profile) is real MSO duplicate though.

Comment: Long addresses mess this up too, though in a different way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ6gc.png Also, the "Network Profile" text is misaligned. Perhaps all these things are related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed:

[image: un-crushed right-hand sidebar on example profile]

There... May be other bugs remaining though:

- [Another bug in the profile page (questions/answers_list)___[I_will_make_this_title_long_enough_to_be_able_to_reproduce_the_issue_on_meta]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375101/another-bug-in-the-profile-page-questions-answers-list-i-will-make-this-tit)
- [Backtick escapes on profile causing terrible display](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316221/backtick-escapes-on-profile-causing-terrible-display)

Comment: Thanks! But what is going on in there? What is causing this bug?

Comment: Massive update to profile markup that broke a ton of other things too. Still bits and pieces broken here & there.