# Stack Exchange® Location Extender™ on profile page ...... again

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

Let me start this with [a previous bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316111/350567): Very long "About me" text squeezes both the left side (flair) and the right side (the section with location, GitHub link, etc.)

Now, the reverse thing has happened:

> [image]

[Ciro Santilli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/895245) put a long text in their "location", and it causes the right section to be overly extended, effectively squeezing the About Me section.

When will the squeezing game end?

Answer (score 3):

As you surmised, this was caused by [a fix for a previous bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316111/stack-exchange-usercard-squeezer-on-profile-page) - that fix removed the maximum width on the stats sidebar.

With all sections now constrained, excessively-long text in any field should result in a layout that, if not necessarily ideal, is at least reasonable.